# Not returning correct value in xml file?

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm trying to get a value from an XML file for a project i'm working on but i cant seem to get it...

This is the XML file:

[image: XML file code]

I tried using

```
    public static String getString(File file, String element) {
    try {
        File fXmlFile = file;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName(element);

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                return eElement.getElementsByTagName("author").item(0).getTextContent();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "Error";
}
```

Using this method to access it

```
File mapdata = new File(HeroVsVilliansCore.getPlugin().getDataFolder(), File.separator + "Maps" + File.separator);
         File f = new File(mapdata, "Test.xml");
```

But it returns "Error" and not the value of "author"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [getDocumentElement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getDocumentElement()) instead of the first getElementsByTagName (by the way what's the value of `element` - should be "map"):

```
return doc.getDocumentElement ()
      .getElementsByTagName("author")
      .item(0).getTextContent();
```

Or split to several statements and chech that the elements have really non zero size.

Comment: Couldn't find "getRootElement()" but i used "getDocumentElement()" and it seems to work.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I pasted link to Jdom instead of standard API. Updated now.

Comment: Works Perfectly!